# How to move GNOME's Application Launcher from bottom to top in Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: unity, launcher, appmenu, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I've just upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to Ubuntu 17.10. I was a fan of Unity desktop environment but after upgrading, I saw that GNOME is also a nice one ('cause it is also very similar to Unity). But there is one thing that makes me uneasy is that Application Launcher is in the bottom. Can't I move it to top-left corner (as it was in Unity)?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It may be a difficult task to move the application launcher to top. Instead, you can install Unity to your system. Here is how:

1. Install Unity by executing this in terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt install unity
   ```
2. Reboot your system.
3. Select "Unity" as desktop environment (by clicking the little cog-wheel beside the sign-in button).
4. Log in by typing in your password.

Done. You can now see that Unity is installed and you also got the application launcher in the top-left of the screen.

Comment: I asked about moving the application launcher to the top. Anyways, let me try that out, seems that it'll work.

Comment: @Geeks'Hangar, It'll surely work, try that out. Let me know if you encounter any errors.

Comment: It worked. Thanks. But it'd be better if I was able to move that application launcher to the top.

Answer (score 5):

Open Terminal and run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-apps-at-top true
```

To move it back to the bottom run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-apps-at-top false
```